# Nginx ЧПУ мультиязычного блога

Tags: php-nginx

Здравствуйте. 
Для мультиязычного блога необходимо построить ЧПУ ссылки.
Eсть физическая страница blog.php, которая принимает GET параметр page:
/blog.php?page=2 должно переадресовывать на /blog/2

Необходимо написать правило для перенаправления с других языковых версий:

```
/blog.php?page=2   =>   /blog/2
/ru/blog.php?page=3   =>   /ru/blog/3
/es/blog.php?page=5   =>   /es/blog/5
```

С данной конструкцией не хочет работать:

```
location ~* /^blog{
        if ($arg_page = 1) {
                return 301 $scheme://$host$uri;
                break;
        }
        if ($arg_page ~ ^(\d+)$) {
                return 301 $scheme://$host$uri/$1;
                break;
        }

}
```

Comment: По-хорошему это всё должно делаться не в nginx, а в php-коде (роутинг называется)

Comment: А почему отдельно отмечено что речь о блоге, это как-то влияет?